# Use of grep "^d" in unix

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I was preparing for a test when I came across a command/expression:

```
grep "^d" | wc -l
```

Can anyone please explain why this command is used?

Comment: Hopefully not to count directories from `ls -l` output -- the best-practice ways to count directories from a script don't involve `ls` at all. `(shopt -s nullglob; set -- */; echo $#)`

Comment: BTW, http://explainshell.com/ is your friend for this class of question. Consider using it first, in the future, and only asking about what's unclear after you've reviewed its results.

Answer (score 2):

“^d” in Unix is also used as an indication of the directory.

```
grep "^d" | wc -l
```

This command can be used to count the number of the directory in a directory, like -

```
ls -lrth | grep "^d" | wc -l
```

To get the count of files only in a directory you can exclude "^d", like -

```
ls -lrth | grep -v "^d" | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

This is used to count the amount of lines (in file or from a pipe) that start with a `d`.

I can imagine that it is used to count the amount of directories in a directory.

Answer (score 1):

`^` in a regular expression means 'at the beginning of a line'.

So yeah this will `grep` for any line starting with `d`

Note that in this case the expression should be:
`grep "^d" -c`, `-c` for count matches, to avoid calling another binary.

Comment: `grep -c '^d'`, rather -- POSIX doesn't require options to be parsed as such if preceded by arguments, so while GNU tools allow the other ordering, they do so as an extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep "^d" | wc -l
string
string
dir
dir2
dir3
3 //Out of wc -l command (ie) grep catches only three lines which started with "d"
```

Execute above command looks for input from standard input after you pass "CTRL + D" which EOF, grep catches ( I would prefer grep greps :) ) only the line starting with "d" and wc -l counts the number of line the grep passes to it.

Basically, grep read from files, pipes and standard input. This is the third case.

Answer (score 0):

[`grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) prints lines that contain a match for a pattern.

So, `grep "^d" | wc -l` counts the number of lines starting with `d`.

Let's say I below lines in `foo.txt`:

```
dline1 abcd
dline2 abcd

line3 abcd
line4 abcd

dline5 abcd
dline6 abcd
```

So, when I run the below command:

```
cat foo.txt | grep "^d" | wc -l
```

It returns `4` because there are 4 lines (line-count) starting with `d`.

`cat foo.txt` returns the file content which is passed as input to `grep "^d"` which returns lines starting with `d` which is passed as input to `wc -l` which finally counts the lines in its input.